# How do I find if variable contains a string from list of strings

Tags: flask, jinja2

How do I check if several strings are not in a variable?

This syntax isn't working and I can't find what is the right syntax...

```
    {% if ('min' or 'max') not in field.label.text %}
        {{ field.label }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ field(class_="selectpicker form-control") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

if `field.label.text` exactly match with 'min' or 'max', then you can use,

```
{% if field.label.text not in ('min' or 'max') %}
```

or, if `field.label.text` contains these words like, `min_range', 'max_value', 'max_num', then use this,

```
{% if not ('max' in field.label.text or 'max' in field.label.text) %}
```